# Поиск в selenium по примерам

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Я недавно начал изучать селениум, и вот сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Дело в том что мне нужно собрать с сайта список элементов, по которым нужно будет перейти.

Я использовал простой код:

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.find_element("//*[@id="thread-4068438"]/div/a")[i]
    cout_post = cout_post + 1
print(f"Найдено элементов {cout_post}")
```

Код на сайте:

```
<a title="" href="threads/4068438/" class="listBlock main PreviewTooltip" data-previewurl="threads/4068438/preview">
```

И возникла такая проблема что идентификатор thread-4068438 всегда будет разный, на каждом посту.
Тогда я попробовал реализовать что то типо такого

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.find_element("class", "listBlock main PreviewTooltip")[i]
    cout_post = cout_post + 1
print(f"Найдено элементов {cout_post}")
```

Но этот код выдал мне ошибку неверного локатора. Я и другие ориентиры ставил. Ничего не помогло.
решил обратиться к опытным людям, может кто то сталкивался и может помочь.
Я бы хотел реализовать что то вроде

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.find_element("//*[@id="(тут что то указать)"]/div/a")[i]
    cout_post = cout_post + 1
print(f"Найдено элементов {cout_post}")
```

Но что бы он искал на месте идентификатора слово thread и игнорировал меняющиеся числа.
Так я бы смог собрать все записи и продолжить работу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут все просто. Используем XPATH и функцию `starts-with`:

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'thread-')]/div/a")[i]
    cout_post = cout_post + 1
print(f"Найдено элементов {cout_post}")
```